# Как установить браузер из командной строки Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, install, opera

Установил `CentOS 8` минимальную версию. Затем поставил туда `xfce`. Минимальный набор браузеров установил так:

```
$ sudo dnf -y install firefox chromium
```

Для полноты <s>зоопарка</s> картины надо ещё добавить туда `opera`, `yandex-browser` и `google-chrome`. Пока хватит. Не хочется скачивать и устанавливать это всё по отдельности `rpm` пакетами, ведь у каждого из них есть свой репозиторий. Обычно пользовался для этого дела браузером. Как это сделать из консоли?

---

<sup>Тот же самый вопрос для Debian: [How to install a browser from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610857/339704)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Тот же самый ответ для Debian: [How to install a browser from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/610858/339704)</sub>

---

Создаём скрипт для установки браузеров, который будет состоять из двух частей: сначала добавляем репозитории браузеров, затем устанавливаем сами браузеры из этих репозиториев. Описания репозиториев те же, что предлагают `rpm` пакеты этих браузеров. `browsers.sh`:

```
sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/opera.repo <<RPMREPO
[opera]
name=Opera packages
type=rpm-md
baseurl=https://rpm.opera.com/rpm
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://rpm.opera.com/rpmrepo.key
enabled=1
RPMREPO

sudo dnf -y install opera-developer opera-stable

sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yandex-browser-beta.repo <<RPMREPO
[yandex-browser-beta]
name=yandex-browser-beta
baseurl=http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/rpm/beta/x86_64
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/YANDEX-BROWSER-KEY.GPG
RPMREPO

sudo dnf -y install yandex-browser-beta

sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo <<RPMREPO
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
RPMREPO

sudo dnf -y install google-chrome-stable
```

---

[opera-developer](/questions/tagged/opera-developer)[opera-stable](/questions/tagged/opera-stable)[yandex-browser-beta](/questions/tagged/yandex-browser-beta)[google-chrome-stable](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-stable)

Answer (score 0):

По идее должен работать прежний принцип:

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
[google-chrome]
name=Chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
skip_if_unavailable=1
EOF
```

затем:

```
sudo dnf update
sudo dnf install chrome
```

`Opera` устанавливается по аналогии.

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/opera.repo
[opera]
name=Opera
baseurl=https://rpm.opera.com/rpm
gpgkey=https://rpm.opera.com/rpmrepo.key
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
skip_if_unavailable=1
EOF
```

Также:

```
sudo dnf update
sudo dnf install opera
```

Ну, и `Стрингерс`:

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/yandex-browser.repo
[yandex-browser]
name=Yandex
baseurl=https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/rpm/
gpgkey=https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/YANDEX-BROWSER-KEY.GPG
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
skip_if_unavailable=1
EOF
```